# Possibility of widespread deployment of IPsec

Tags: ipsec

I want to know if IPsec is a candidate for a widespread deployment in the Internet. So far IPsec seems to be adopted merely in VPN networks.
IPsec seems to have problems with [NAT-traversal](http://www.uninet.edu/6fevu/text/IPSEC-NAT.SGML.html) and another disadvantage (in my opinion) is that it is rather complicated and might suffer from difficult configuration tasks.

Nevertheless with the transition into an IPv6 Internet, what are the pros and cons you see towards/against widespread communication protection with IPsec?

Comment: IPv6 doesn't support NAT.  The original spec for IPv6, IIRC, included a requirement of IPSec.